# Is my database design good enough?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a problem statement to create a database for a `Stock Management` company. Business model is basically their `Clients` give them money and the company go and invest them in `Stock Borkers`. Some of the business rules are below.

1. Client can have more than 1 account.
2. There are 2 types of accounts, `Starting account` and `Active account`.
3. There are 2 types of Investments, `Local` and `International`. Client can select with which investment type they move forward.
4. Client have a `Adviser` and a `Broker`. However company allow the `Client` to register first without giving these information. Later when `Client` provide these information, his records will be updated. Company by themselves will decide which `Broker` they should allocate.
5. `Client` "might" have an `Sub Agent`.
6. `Client` will credit and debit money to his account.
7. Once invested, company will update the Client's Account with the new investment values and cash values. These values should be monitored separately.
8. `Client` will have a `Starting Account` as soon as he provided the money to the company. `Client` will have a `Active Account` as soon as the company assigned a `Broker` to them.

Below is my ER Diagram.
[image]

I know it is a time taking task, but I really appreciate if someone can tell me "How good" my design is, and whether it requires any change. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

May answering some questions lead us to better design:

1. Having an association table called `client_account` is telling me
   that an account could be shared between multiple clients. if not,
   that may be redundant. the relation to broker entity could be
   accomplished in account table.
2. If and only if `account_type` and `investment_type` have predefined
   static values like:

   > Starting account, Active account and Local, International

   There will be no need to define them as tables, you may use domain
   objects (enumeration).
3. Being an active account can be a boolaen attribute of account table, not a
   separate table.
4. If transaction(debit and credit) can be done between accounts (double accounting) then
   you need to have a `transaction_detail` table as a child to
   `transaction` table. Account relation need to be accomplished in
   `transaction_detail` table, not in `transaction` table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding your point 1, is it wrong to have that table? Accounts are not shared, these are `stock accounts` not bank accounts.

Comment: What will happen if we remove client_account table and having client FK in account table?

Comment: Nothing will happen. It will still work. I craeted a new `client_account` because it is easy to search and may help to address any future additions?

Comment: Meanwhile, database can have tables that are not conneted to anywhere right? In cases where the user just need to enter and see the saved data, not to use it in any operation etc?

Comment: There will be join operation cost in your search operation. First for  client and second for account.